# create upload progress bar using zend and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

i have to create upload center site like speedyshare.com with zend but i don't have any idea how to create progress bar to show upload progress .

any idea or a tutorial to doing this ?

Comment: Google it. We are not hear to Google for you, or do your homework or do your job.

Comment: There are lots of flash and javascript upload scripts out there. As has been said: Google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File upload progress bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612630/file-upload-progress-bar)

Comment: Search first... there are a LOT of duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067802/creating-a-custom-upload-progress-bar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866212/how-to-create-the-upload-progress-bar-using-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448328/upload-progress-bar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158853/creating-a-file-progress-bar-in-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849237/upload-progress-bar-in-php

Answer (score 1):

I used this: http://www.uploadify.com/
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Claire Sosset from the CENTURION team has an answer for you **[HTML5 Multiple File Upload with Progress Bar](http://www.centurion-project.org/articles/html5-multiple-file-upload-with-progress-bar)**.

Tell us if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try FancyUpload: http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/